# Is there a way with boost Ptree writing Json to not escape "/" to "\/" at the root level?

Tags: c++, boost

I am using the boost PTree object to write out a Json files and it escapes all "/" ( forward slash ) in the output to "\/" - It will parse un-escaped '/' in input fine.  Unescaped '/' is legal Json.

Is there a way to turn off this slash escaping behavior setting a value or entering a flag at the root "write json" for the whole tree without modifying the boost source ?

It makes unix paths in json fields really ugly and confusing to some users.

Comment: ptree isn't the best way of writing json, I'd recommend using a dedicated json library instead

Comment: you might just be able to delete this [line](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/88a3b0ba8a6cd4ddf35f10d841bde9878241d64a/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser/detail/write.hpp#L45)